# SQL Server - Convert decimal to string with padding - implied decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a need to format numbers with padded zeros left and right. The number's precision is decimal (9,5). I am converting to a character string and need it to be a length of 4.
I am using SQL server 2008.

Here are some examples:

```
If 3.0 then I need 0003
If 30.0 then I need 0030
If 112.8 then I need 1128
If 120.0 then I need 1200
```

and so on.

I have tried multiple format functions like Right, Left, Replace, etc. But no combinations seem to get me the correct format.

Example below:

```
Right('00' + Replace(SUBSTRING(CAST(My_Table.My_Field as varchar),1,4),'.',''),4)
```

It works fine for the number 36.0 but this gets me 0212 for the number 212.0. I need it to be 2120

Comment: At what number do you start including decimal places? What is the “correct format” for 99.9?

Comment: I deleted my answer for now... working on a solution.

Comment: How will be for the case 31.3? 0313?

Comment: Why does 3.0 = 0003, 30.0 = 0030, and 120.0 = 1200? Shouldn't 120.0 = 0120 to fit the pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Another one

```
right('000'+replace(value,'.',''),4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following sql code will be useful:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN  NUMBER < 100
  THEN RIGHT('0000' + CAST(CAST(NUMBER AS INT) AS VARCHAR),4)
  ELSE RIGHT(SUBSTRING(CAST(NUMBER AS VARCHAR),1,CHARINDEX('.',CAST(NUMBER AS VARCHAR))-1),4) + LEFT(PARSENAME(NUMBER,1),1)
END RESULT
FROM TEST
```

You can try this here **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b0a5/1)**.

Note: NUMBER is your field, and TEST is your TABLE.

Answer (score 1):

If 3.0 is supposed to be 0030 and 30.0 is supposed to be 0300, which would make sense for if 120.0 is supposed to be 1200, then this select statement should work:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('0000'||REPLACE(TableName.NumberColumn,'.',''),-4,4) AS Output FROM TableName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Value DECIMAL(4,1))

INSERT INTO @temp (Value)
VALUES (3.0),(30.0), (112.8),(120.0)

SELECT RIGHT('000' + CAST(CAST(Value * 10 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) 
FROM @temp
```

Output -

```
----
0030
0300
1128
1200
```